# Setting the HTTPOnly flag for PHPSESSID cookie

Tags: php, cookies

I am getting this message from my security audit:

> Cookie name: "PHPSESSID"
>
> Cookie domain: "xxx.xxx.xx.xxx"
>
> If possible, you should set the HTTPOnly flag for this cookie.

How can I set the HTTPOnly flag for this cookie?

Answer (score 7):

You have at least 3 ways to achieve that:

1. In the PHP configuration file (php.ini), look for **session.cookie_httponly** setting and set it to True.
2. If you don't have access to PHP configuration, you can try to overwrite this setting at runtime:

> ```
> ini_set("session.cookie_httponly", 1);
> ```

3. If it doesn't work, you have to manually overwrite that cookie:

> ```
> session_start();
> $params = session_get_cookie_params();
> setcookie("PHPSESSID", session_id(), 0, $params["path"], $params["domain"],
>     false,  // this is the secure flag you need to set. Default is false.
>     true  // this is the httpOnly flag you need to set
> );
> ```

---

`setcookie()` [definition](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php):

```
bool setcookie ( string $name [, string $value = "" [, int $expire = 0 [, string $path = "" [, string $domain = "" [, bool $secure = false [, bool $httponly = false ]]]]]] )
```

Comment: this code is not working  error The page isn't redirecting properly

Comment: If you eg. use over-restricted hosting, your server configuration may prevent you from implementing all above solutions. You should then contact your administrator and ask directly about turning on session.cookie_httponly setting.